# Calling an if function two times inside a jsf tag

Tags: java, function, jsf, if-statement

Looking directly at the tag will be easier to understand my problem, the question goes inside the styleClass attribute:

```
<h:outputText value="#{prod.actualStock}" 
styleClass="
#{productBean.getSeverity(prod.actualStock, prod.replacementAlertLevel).equals('INFO') ?
'severity-info' : productBean.getSeverity(prod.actualStock, prod.replacementAlertLevel).equals('WARN') ?
'severity-warn' : 'severity-danger'}" />
```

Now, note that I'm calling two times the 'getSeverity()' function, each of the three returns gives a different style class for the outputText. Is there a way to call the function only once keeping the same logic?

The '' tag goes inside a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just have the getSeverity method return the class name as a string?

Comment: sure, sorry about that. need to clear my mind! haha. THank you!

Comment: You should separate the presentation logic from the business logic. Setting the CSS value from the managed bean it's not a good solution. It should have a property to handle the severity value and make the comparison in the JSF code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another attribute in your `ProductBean` class that holds the result of `ProductBean#getSeverity` and you set it in your managed bean before using it in the `<h:dataTable>`

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class Bean {
    private List<ProductBean> productBean;
    //getters and setters...

    //I'm assuming you fill the list here
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        productBean = ...
        for(ProductBean pb : productBean) {
            pb.setSeverityValue(pb.getSeverity(<parameters>));
        }
    }
}
```

In your JSF code, you just call the property

```html
<h:outputText value="#{prod.actualStock}"
    styleClass="#{productBean.severityValue.equals('INFO') ? 'severity-info' : productBean.severityValue.equals('WARN') ? 'severity-warn' : 'severity-danger'}" />
```

Comment: +1! As you commented in my now deleted answer, you're right. I tought he was invoking a bean method but when I saw your comment I double-checked the question and noticed that. With this in mind, the answer I come with (and an alternative to yours) is to make a method in the bean that receives a product as a parameter and returns the CSS class.